# How to stretch Layout background Image as per child content?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to stretch layout background image as per child's content. I am using relative layout and set bubble image as its background.
In that relative layout i have add ImageView and TextView as child.
some content of textview  or image size is bigger then bubble image.

How can i fix it?

Thank you in advance.....

Here is my bubble image

[image]
with image..

[image]
wthout image

[image]
original bubble image..

Comment: showing some code would help. Atleast the xml layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should convert that image to a 9 patch. Android system takes care of stretching the 9 patch images depending on the stretchable regions you define on it.